# How can I make this angular controller re-usable thoughout the site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angularjs-directive

I have this tab functionality made in AngularJS and I want it to be re-usable throughout my website without having to repeat the logic. Is there a way I can make it a directive? or maybe a service?

Here is the html:

```
<ul class="expandingTab">
    <li ng-class="{active: isSet(1)}"><a href="#" ng-click="setTab(1)"><span>MY GMM</span></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: isSet(2)}"><a href="#" ng-click="setTab(2)"><span>ALL TRANSACTIONS</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="isSet(1)">
    <h1>Tab 1</h1>
</div>
<div ng-show="isSet(2)">
    <h1>Tab 2</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TabController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function(tab) {
       $scope.tab = tab;
    };

    $scope.isSet = function(checkTab) {
       return $scope.tab === checkTab;
    };
}]);
```

**EDIT**

I really would like to just have the functionality in a service and be able to inject it as a dependency to controllers that will use it. This way I can keep all the content in the view where I want it. I feel like my logic is close, but I still can't get it working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

HTML

```
<ul class="expandingTab">
  <li ng-class="{active: tabs.toggleTabs.isSet(1)}"><a href="#" ng-click="tabs.toggleTabs.setTab(1)"> <span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
  <li ng-class="{active: tabs.toggleTabs.isSet(2)}"><a href="#" ng-click="tabs.toggleTabs.setTab(2)"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="tabs.toggleTabs.isSet(1)">
  <h1>Tab 1</h1>
</div>
<div ng-show="tabs.toggleTabs.isSet(2)">
  <h1>Tab 2</h1>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['services']);

app.controller('TabController', ['$scope', 'toggleTabs',function($scope, toggleTabs) {

}]);
```

Service

```
var tabsApp = angular.module('services', []);

tabsApp.service('toggleTabs', function() {
  this.tab = 1;
  this.setTab = function(tabSelected) {
    this.tab = tabSelected;
  }
  this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
    return this.tab === checkTab;
  }
});
```

And here is a Plunker with all this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/liT7BIGlIRg9boH81NaY?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comments, here is an example that shows how you can inject content into the directive to make it more reusable. It doesn't use tabs, but it illustrates the concept. [JsBin example](http://jsbin.com/qubihiyutiqo/2/edit?html,js,output).

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="testController">
  <header bf-nav navs="navs"></header>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('test', []);

  app.directive('bfNav', navDirective);

  function navDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        navs: '='
      },
      template: '<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"><div class="container-fluid"><ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li ng-repeat="nav in navs" ng-click="setNav(nav.index)" ng-class="{ active: isActive(nav.index) }"><a href="#">{{nav.title}}</a></li></ul></div></nav>',
      controller: navController
    };
  }

  function navController($scope) {
    $scope.activeNav = 1;

    $scope.isActive = function (index) {
      return $scope.activeNav === index;
    };

    $scope.setNav = function (index) {
      $scope.activeNav = index;
    };
  }

  app.controller('testController', ['$scope', testController]);

  function testController($scope) {
    $scope.navs = [
      { index: 1, title: 'Nav 1' },
      { index: 2, title: 'Nav 2' }
    ];
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like your code and am hoping you can help me put the last piece together. I need to account for the content that the tabs hide/show, but I want to have that HTML in the view and not the JS like the titles. How can I place the hidden div's outside the directive and have the ng-show="isSet(1)" still access the directive's controller?

Comment: @Ian Idk if I understand you completely, but, just like how the navs in my example are repeated, you would repeat the tab content divs in the same way to account for each tab. The title and content of each tab must exist outside of the template in some format (i.e. JSON served from a web service, flat file, or manually input) and injected into the directive as shown; otherwise, your directive isn't reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Your directive is not working because you have not specified a 'template' for it (your html) in conjunction with using an isolate scope (scope: {}). Basically the directive cannot talk to the html that you have put the *tabs* on. (among other things)

Try:

```
ocApp.directive('tabs', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'tabs.html', //Put your html into a seperate file and add the path here
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.tab = 1;

            $scope.setTab = function(tab){
                $scope.tab = tab;
            };

            $scope.isSet = function(checkTab){
                return $scope.tab === checkTab;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

For tabs.html

```
<ul class="expandingTab">
    <li ng-class="{active: isSet(1)}"><a href="#" ng-click="setTab(1)"><span>MY GMM</span></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: isSet(2)}"><a href="#" ng-click="setTab(2)"><span>ALL TRANSACTIONS</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="isSet(1)">
    <h1>Tab 1</h1>
</div>
<div ng-show="isSet(2)">
    <h1>Tab 2</h1>
</div>
```

And for index.html you would use

```
<div tabs></div>
```

or

```
<tabs></tabs>
```

I'd recommend [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) reference for directives (there are many other resources on the googles and on SO)

Comment: Would you say this is a better approach than using a factory or service? I am wondering how I will set the content of the tabs.html when re-using it on different pages.

Comment: What are you using this for? A header? or is this a component inside your app?

Comment: It's a component inside an app for toggling various content

Comment: @Ian This is the approach you should use. Directives are intended to be used for creating reusable components. A factory or service would be a bad choice. To change the tab content, you can pass that data into the directive itself via its isolated scope property.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this as a service and it seems to be just what I wanted. I can keep the html in the view and just inject the service into whatever controller I want to use tabs on here is the code:

HTML

```
<ul class="expandingTab">
  <li ng-class="{active: .toggleTabs.isSet(1)}"><a href="#" ng-click="toggleTabs.setTab(1)"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
  <li ng-class="{active: toggleTabs.isSet(2)}"><a href="#" ng-click="toggleTabs.setTab(2)"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="toggleTabs.isSet(1)">
  <h1>Tab 1</h1>
</div>
<div ng-show="toggleTabs.isSet(2)">
  <h1>Tab 2</h1>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['services']);

app.controller('TabController', ['$scope', 'toggleTabs',function($scope, toggleTabs) {
   $scope.toggleTabs = toggleTabs;
}]);
```

Service

```
var tabsApp = angular.module('services', []);

tabsApp.service('toggleTabs', function() {
  this.tab = 1;
  this.setTab = function(tabSelected) {
    this.tab = tabSelected;
  }
  this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
    return this.tab === checkTab;
  }

});
```